# Remote Test runner debug - "Source not found"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and facing this problem while deubugging code, I tried to search for source but didn't know the name of the source it needs.

[image]

I tried to add source by click edit source look up then choose Java project then choose my project instead of default folder but didn't work.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun thanks for finding the duplicate post but i tried the solution didn't work with me

Comment: I reopened the question, please specify that in the post itself and try to describe your attempt.

Comment: i edited post , thanks for reopened post

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not able to find the source for Junit3TestLoader. It is not complaining about not finding your source.

This is part of the eclipse.jdt.junit plug in.

Either import the plug in as a source or attach the plugin source by clicking the Edit source look up path.

Comment: thanks for helping but where can i find eclipse.jdt.junit ?

Comment: You can download the eclipse installation with source plug ins...once you get that you can import the source plug in and the source for jdt.ui.junit will automatically come...but do you want junit plug in's code or your code to be displayed ?

Comment: the actual problem i'm facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556085/variable-read-in-main-folder-not-test-folder but when i used debug i faced the problem above in the post so i think i should solve it to know where is the problem as i think or is it  not important ?