# variable read in main folder not test folder

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I'm facing a strange problem.
Here I have 2 folders in the project for main and for test
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I defined public static variable in class in `trident.functions`, then used it in another class in `entities` by taking object form class, here everything is OK and variable is read well as it holds a number due to an equation I wrote, then stored result in this variable.

Problem with me in test folder. When I maven code I got failure with test classes when I debugged code I found that variable that I defined before hold zero not number, why this variable not read number, however it worked well before with other classes in main?

```
public class Vector implements Function {
    public static  double num;
    String words[]={"asd","wer","dfdf","rttyy"}
    public  Values getValues(Tweet tweet, String[] words){
    //this part of the code of the variable i defined 

        for(String w:words)
        {
            items.add(w);
        }
        num = items.size();
    }
     public Spar normVector(Spar vector) {
         double z = vector.getnum();
         vector = //some calculations on z ; 
         return vector;
     }
}
```

another class

```
public class Spar {
     public double getnum() {
         double x=Vector.num;
         return x;
     }
}
```

Test class

```
public class VectorTest { 
    Vector  vb;
    public VectorBuilderTest(String vbr) {
        super(vbr);
        vb = new VectorBuilder();
    }
    public void testNormalizeVector() {
        Spar sp = new Spar(values);
        Spar normalized = vb.normVector(sp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blake Yarbrough do you have information about this ?

Comment: Could you show the code that you are describing?

Comment: Without source code we can only guess. Maybe you don't call the code that sets the variable from your test cases.

Comment: i hope that to fix the problem faster but which part do you need ?

Comment: The class containing variable and the test that fails might help but please try and provide a short example and don't dump loads of code here.

Comment: i edited post hope it help beacue really code is more than this but i wrote the parts which i debugged on it and found the problem

Comment: @ScottHunter where are you ? can you help ?

Comment: @pkalinow where are you ? can you help ?

Comment: @Thomas where are you ? can you help ?

Comment: If I may suggest something:
1. Don't use mutable static fields unless really necessary. 
2. Don't use public fields, as it breaks one of the OOP principles - isolation.
3. Use meaningful names for methods and variables. "num" or "z" are not good names.

Answer (score 1):

The code has several issues. It would not even compile.

1. The local variable `words` in `getValues` is duplicated (compile error).
2. The method `normVector` is declared to return `Spar` but it returns `double` (compile error).
3. In the test class the field vb is not initialized i.e. null, so the line `Spar normalized = vb.normVector(sp);` would throw a `NullPointerException` (runtime error).
4. The static variable `num` is set only in the method getValues, but it is not called from your test class at all.

Comment: thanks for helping , you are right , i edited the post as i wrote code is large to write it all here , but i tried to mention the lines that debugging used it and found varaibles is zero , i rewrite first 3 steps but step number 4 i did't get you well

Comment: @user1 In 4. I meant that you never change the variable `num` - so it can have only one value: 0. At least the code snippet with VectorTest does not call any method that changes the value.

Comment: But  test class call method normvector  in class Vector that make calculations in z by implement method getnum that in class Spar , and varabile here got zero although it should has number as i got object from class Vector which has variable with number , is it right ?

Comment: The field `public static  double num;` is initialized by 0 (zero) when the class is loaded. No visible code changes its value, so it remains 0.

Comment: When you assign the value of `num` to another variable, like in `getnum()`, only *value* of the field is being copied, not the field itself. So, when you make calculations on `z`, it has no effect to `Vector.num`, unless you assign the value of `z` to `num` explicitly: `Vector.num = z;`.

Comment: Thanks for your interest . but I made calculations on num in vector class . Is this value stored in num ? I tested this classes i mean vector and spar classes without test class and worked well and variable num contains number not zero but problem with test class that read variable with zero

Comment: "Is this value stored in num?" - how could I know it? You haven't provided the code that does it so I don't know.

Comment: Yes value stored in this variable . sorry I'm not asking you this question. I'm wonder from this failure . why test class not reading value ?

Comment: Maybe because you call another class? `vb = new VectorBuilder();` If normVector() is overridden in VectorBuilder, it may behave differently than in Vector. Anyway, talking about code without code is pointless IMHO.

Comment: I added what you need to know in this error as I said before that my code is very large . i'm really appreciate your time for helping me . thanks